# Commemorative patent prints/canvases/etc

Tags: gift

I wondering if there's a service you use to print patent entries in a decorative/commerative manner - full text and images. My grandfather submitted [US3281099](http://www.google.com/patents/US3281099) and I thought if I can have a 'keepsake' copy made it would be a nice gift to my mom.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the USPTO does not does sell commemorative patent plaques.  However, there are a number of companies which will create engraved plaques and various other certificates based on US Patents.

Start with a [Google Search](https://www.google.com/#q=commemorative+patent+plaque&safe=off).

We have had good luck creating gifts for friends with patents engraved on metal and mounted on solid walnut from a company called PlaqueMaker.com: http://www.plaquemaker.com/PatentPlaque.html

Comment: While @ryan is asking about an old patent, I think it is worth stating for others that several of these companies specifically advertise to new patent recipients. If you obtain a patent, you will get (very official-looking) mail congratulating you and offering to sell plaques, certificates, or other displayable items.